# Two floats with different width style

Tags: css, width, css-float

Is it possible to have two floats with .left width in pixel and .right in percentage? So whenever .left changes its width, .right will just adjust automatically.
For example:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the width of the right one in percentages at all:

I just modified Blender's example, since his example was incorrect as the #wrap element was not 500px wide, but 600px instead.

```
#wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;

    padding: 5px 0;

    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(220, 200, 200);
}

.right {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 220);
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KSzy6/)

Update:

If right is taller then left, then you need to change right's style to this:

```
.right {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 220);
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Also, remove the hight from #wrap, you don't need it there anyways...

Comment: I guess this will not work if the .right has a height greater than .left

Comment: +1 for shorter code. And just a FYI, your `#wrap` is `500px` wide too :P

Comment: My #wrap is 500px wide, yours was 600px cause of the extra -100px margin. Not a huge deal, really, just need to remember to make #wrap width to be the result width - width of left.

Answer (score 0):

use LESScss (lesscss.org)! what you can do is set a variable to contain the width (percentage) of an element, and then subtract that from the total to auto-adjust the width of the other

```
@width1: 50%;
@width2: 100%-@width1;
.left {
    width: @width1;
}
.right {
    width: @width2;
}
```

Comment: I like LESS :) it's still an answer, @Blender

Comment: so @Blender - write up an answer

Comment: I'm not here to argue with you, but if you insist, I shall.

Comment: your first reply started an argument

Comment: Again, I'm not here to argue. Please stop promoting/starting an argument.

Comment: If you want to compare, mine doesn't depend on a JavaScript library to parse it's CSS-like language, which means that it won't break when users without JavaScript try to browse the site. And if you speak about length, you didn't include the OP's original CSS, so yours wins by two lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tad long, but conceptually understandable (to me anyways):

```
#wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;

    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-left: 100px; /* Width of static */

    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    float: left;
    margin-left: -100px; /* Negative width of self */
}

.right {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;

    float: left;
}
```

Here's a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/scXm5/22/)** (stretch the box a little to see).